# Verification of intro level proof for vector algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

I have been independently working proofs out of a vector calculus book I own and would like feedback on one of them; if it's right; if it is right, could it be improved; etc. 
Here is the problem:
(Also, I apologize in advance, I don't have software to let me type math equations. Please read numbers and lower-case letters attached to the right of capital letters as subscripts.)

Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_r$ be non-zero vectors which are mutually perpendicular, or in other words, $A_i\cdot A_j = 0$ iff $i\ne j$. Let $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_r$ be real numbers such that 
$c_1A_1 + \ldots + c_rA_r = \mathbf{0}$. 
Prove that all $c_i = 0$.

My attempt:
$c_1A_1 + \ldots + c_rA_r = \mathbf{0}$

(take the dot product of each side and $A_r$)

$A_r\cdot(c_1A_1 + \ldots + c_rA_r) = A_r \cdot\mathbf{0}$

reduces to

$c_r(A_r\cdot A_r) = 0$

(divide both sides by $A_r\cdot A_r$)

$c_r = 0.$

Since $r$ is arbitrary, any $c_r$ must be zero. QED.

Is this a sufficient proof of the question asked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. *Which* software do you think you need to let you type math expressions?

Comment: The proof is good, maybe you should just say why you can divide by $A_r \cdot A_r$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . All you need to type maths is just the basic ASCII alphabet.